# How to clear the autocompleteTextView string when change the tabhost fragment one to another in android

Tags: android, tabs, fragment-tab-host

I am new in android development,I am not able to clear the data when change the tab fragment in android.

Comment: show your code .. your effort

Comment: You could make use of setUserVisibleHint() of Fragment class to know when the fragment is visible to the user & write the AutocompleteTextView clearing code when it is not visible to user. @Anuj Kumar

Comment: I already try with setUserVisibleHint() but doesn't resolved this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `setOnTabChangedListener` on tabHost. Then override it's methods. Now clear your all data in `onTabChanged(String tabId)` method. You can identify tab from this method String parameter. Then handle your data according to tab.

Comment: don't have viewpager,Actually i am using tabHost with fragment @Kinal Mer